# Index out of range while

Tags: python

can anyone help me? Why this go index out of range. The precise moment is at the statement "if testo[k] not in vocali:"

```
while k < len(testo):
    if testo[k] == '\n':
        sillaba += testo[k]
        k += 1
        Es.append(sillaba)
        sillaba = ""
    if testo[k] not in vocali:
        sillaba += testo[k]
        k += 1
        if v:
            Es.append(sillaba[:-1])
            k -= 1
            v = False
            sillaba = ""
    else:
        sillaba += testo[k]
        k += 1
        v = True
```

Comment: What does `testo` contain? Can you add the full backtrace your post? Also, what is the value  of `k`

Comment: If `k` was at the end of `testo` and found a `\n` it got incremented past the end of `testo` in the 4th line, so in the 9th line it's going to be out of range.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, There is "\n" at the end of `testo` due to which `if testo[k] == '\n'` results `True` and `k += 1` runs, incrementing the value of `k` to value greater than the length of `testo`. Hence, `if testo[k] not in vocali:` gives **index out of range** error.

Simple fix would be to check if `k` would be greater than length of `testo` before incrementing `k`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Carcigenicate pointed out the problem, but I can't comment yet so I am writing here. What is happening is when value of `k` is `len(testo) - 1` and the program gets inside the while loop the first if statement i.e. `if testo[k] == '\n'`  comes out to be true(assuming that `testo` is a string) then the execution goes inside the selection statements and `k` is incremented again which implies that now `k` is equal to `len(testo)` when execution is passed on to the second `if` statement and program checks for the condition it finds the index to be out of range and hence the error.

```py
while k < len(testo):
    if testo[k] == '\n':
        sillaba += testo[k]
        k += 1
        Es.append(sillaba)
        sillaba = ""
        continue

    if testo[k] not in vocali:
        sillaba += testo[k]
        k += 1
        if v:
            Es.append(sillaba[:-1])
            k -= 1
            v = False
            sillaba = ""
    else:
        sillaba += testo[k]
        k += 1
        v = True
```

You can add a `continue` statement to send the execution to the next iteration to avoid the error.